# Delete at most one file matching a pattern

Tags: bash

In bash, I would like to remove the first file which conforms to a pattern (say *.txt).

```
rm *.txt
```

Will remove all.  Is there a simple way to just remove the first?

Comment: What would be "the first" file?

Comment: the first in the list that *.txt resolves to  (or the first alphabetically).

Comment: `set -- *.txt; rm "$1"`

Comment: Great, thank you.  If you make it an answer I'll tick it ;)